# Android Final variable error

Tags: android, variables, for-loop, final

i have this code, which is called from a for loop

```
void var_init(String to_match,String[][] temp) {

        String t_match=to_match;
    //problem in the below line

        String t_replace = "";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RuleEngine.this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Value for"+t_match);

// Set up the input
        final EditText input = new EditText(RuleEngine.this);

        builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               t_replace = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
```

It gives me an error that the t_replace i saccessed from the inner class and should be declared as final, when i add the final with t_replace variable then it says that can not assign value to a final t_replace variable. it suggeste me to convert it into one element array which runs fine but the results returned are not what is intended.

Comment: use t_replace as an instance variable right at the begining of the class. Not inside any methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can 't_replace' global.
You can not modify final, because they are constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify final variables in run-time 
you 'd remove final keyword
`final EditText input = new EditText(RuleEngine.this);`

Answer (score 0):

When a `final` variable holds a reference to an object, it means that the content of the object can be modified but the variable will always point to the same object. 
Besides, if you need to access a variable from an inner class, like in this case, you need to declare it as `final`. Afterwards, you are free to change its value (it's not a constant).

Therefore, at the beginning of your code, just add

```
final String t_replace = "";
```